# Why am I unable to turn of USB debugging on my Galaxy Tab 10.1?

Tags: usb-debugging, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I turned on USB Debugging in the settings and am unable to turn it off. Whenever I try to uncheck the option I get "USB is connected. Remove the cable." even though the cable is not connected.

I tried rebooting but nothing. I do not think my device has ever completely turned off. When I try to power down it has a green battery animation of it filling up. I do not know how to completely turn it off.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your tab thinks it's charging from a USB socket all the time, I'd advise to get it checked under warranty, or you could try to let the battery run completely out and then recharge. Also, check the USB port for debris and clean if necessary.